# Custom button in RadioButton not displayed

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, radio-button

I want to create custom button for a RadioButton by creating a selectable for the checked and unchecked state. But nothing is displayed in place of the buttons.

My code:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">

        <RadioButton
            style="@style/TitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="email"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selectable"/>

        <RadioButton
            style="@style/TitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="anonymous"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:checked="true"
            android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selectable"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

radio_button_selectable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_selected"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_unselected"/>

</selector>
```

radio_button_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#FFF95B"
        android:startColor="#FF930F" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

radio_button_unselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

How it looks:

[Screenshot of radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVRDd.png)

Answer (score 0):

change this code:

android:background="@drawable/radio_button_selectable"
android:button="@null"/

```
  <RadioButton
        style="@style/TitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="anonymous"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_button_selectable"
        android:button="@null"/>
```

Comment: It works. But button image fully overlaps text.